# Get specific versions of TFS code in a different directory

Tags: tfs, svnbridge

Currently we have a build process as follows:

1. I do a build into our dev staging environment.
2. I label this in TFS.
3. I use SVN bridge to check out that changeset that was labelled.*
4. If testing for dev staging passes, I use the working copy I checked out to do another build into the next environment.

I don't want to have to use SVN Bridge to have a copy of my code somewhere else for code at a specific version, but I have not found a way to do this natively in TFS (2010).

Is there a way of doing this (point 3 and 4) using TFS, instead of SVN Bridge?

Comment: Is there a reason that you are not using the tfs build agents to do your builds?

Comment: We are using the TFS build agents to do nightly builds. However we don't want to build for every environment every time, only once the appropriate testing/passing is done for the current environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be completely misunderstanding what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you need to create a separate workspace, and get the code that was labeled in step 2 into the new workspace.

Comment: Thanks @Dan , it is in line with what I want to do, but I don't want to create a workspace every time I want to do a build.

Comment: @Russell - You could re-use the workspace, and use the -force option when you get the files. I'm sure there are other options as well.

Comment: The issue with reusing the workspace is if (For example) I want to deploy version 3 into dev staging, but during that time I may want to deploy version 2 (which was in system test) to UAT.